# How to remove space from a title column in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, flow, power-automate

I am sure this question has been asked many times, but would someone please be able to guide me with my issue with removing a space between title word, e.g. title "Project ABC" and I would like it to show in calculated column "ProjectABC".

Comment: How many spaces will be in title column? Or is it variable like any number of spaces in text? Also, do you want to use this calculated value somewhere else or you just want to show it in list view?

Comment: depens how the title will be called, it could be e.g. "Project resovling any issues" then you have 3 spaces which shall be removed. hence i cant define how many spaces will be there... but its a title which should be short.

I just want it show in a list view i wont be using it anywhere else

Comment: Can you explain the exact reason why you want to remove spaces? With calculated columns it's quite hard or even impossible to achieve, because calculated columns don't provide a replace function. I would go with Power Automate! :)

Comment: I see....

I am trying to create a sharepoint subsite using power automate and use the title with no space as URL title to create the site with the title
based on following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPVn1yQYtME.

may be its possible to create it withouth the calculated column, but i thought if you have spaces in the title it will create %20 in the URL when created

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Power automate to create a site without space, you don't need to create calculated column for this.

You can use `replace` function in expression in Power automate to remove the spaces from text.

Syntax of expression will be like:

```
replace('Project resolving any issues', ' ', '')
```

You can also pass variables or columns from SharePoint list in expressions instead of "'Project resolving any issues'" text.

**Documentation**: [Replace function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#replace)

---

If you want to know more about how to use expressions, check this: [Introduction to expressions in Power Automate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-expressions/)

Comment: Hi @Helena, did you try this solution? Is it working for you? Let me know if you still have any question related this solution.